# Tensorflow/Keras: how to get the output of an Input layer by channels?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have an Input layer that looks like this:

```
>>>inp = tf.keras.Input(shape=(107, 3))
>>>print(inp)
Tensor("input_25:0", shape=(None, 107, 3), dtype=float32)
```

Since the shape is `(None, 107, 3)`, I want to take each `(None, 107, 1)` to use it for separate layers. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [a related GitHub issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5474#issuecomment-281661333), you can use `tf.keras.layers.Lambda` to split the input tensor by channel.

```
import tensorflow as tf

tfkl = tf.keras.layers
inp = tf.keras.Input(shape=(107, 3))

x0 = tfkl.Lambda(lambda x : x[..., 0])(x)
x1 = tfkl.Lambda(lambda x : x[..., 1])(x)
x2 = tfkl.Lambda(lambda x : x[..., 2])(x)
```

The `...` is an `Ellipsis` and fills in the slices to get the last slice only.